# Client connect issue with adding error handling

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to an account on Splunk via Python and Bash. I can connect to the website fine and it prints what I want it to, in the terminal, when I log in correctly. However when I use the wrong log in details, it prints a large error message saying 'login failed' that I want to try and condense to one line only.
This is what I am using to connect to Splunk:

```
service = client.connect(
    host=splunk_config['host'],
    port=splunk_config['port'],
    username=splunk_config['username'],
    password=splunk_config['password'])
```

I want to do something along the lines of:

```
if (service errors):
   print ("Failed to connect")
else:
   print ("Successfully connected")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the exception and guessing you're using splunklib I would imagine you need something like:

```
try:
    service = client.connect(
        host=splunk_config['host'],
        port=splunk_config['port'],
        username=splunk_config['username'],
        password=splunk_config['password'])
    print("Login succesfull")
except splunklib.binding.AuthenticationError as e:
    print("Login failed")
```

Comment: I am not using splunklib unfortunately - I am getting the username and password from the terminal using bash and then using those in the python file. Thank you for the try and except I am not sure why I didnt think of that haha!

Comment: Doesn't matter where you get the username and password from. What matters is what lib you're using to create the connection to splunk. Anyways. Cool if this answered your question please accept it as the answer

Comment: I am not using a library to connect - I am using ```nc -vz -w1 $splunk_host $splunk_port &> /dev/null``` to connect to the splunk server but then just the client.connect()

Comment: Oh. That's a little round about way of doing it but ok. In theory the try catch will just have to be edited to catch the exception that's being thrown when you try to connect. I could help you further if the question is updated with the exception and the login code where you run the nc command.

Comment: I am refactoring some old files so some of it is a bit round haha. I think I have managed to get it working though so thank you very much!